# Reading from text file to load images from resource folder

Tags: java, image, imageicon

I wanted to make a way so that I can load all the Images in my source folder without having to code each line for each image, but I keep getting an error and have tried different ways to do this and I still can't figure it out. Is it just impossible?

Here is how it works: I save all the images I am going to need on a text file (in this case `startUp.txt`), then I store the lines in the text file in a linked-list(String) then I use a loop to get the images and store those in a linked-list(Image) so that I don't need to write code for every single Image to load.

Here is my code:

```
package com.game.task;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class imagesTest {

public LinkedList<Image> storeImages = new LinkedList<Image>();
private LinkedList<String> storeStrings = new LinkedList<String>();

public imagesTest() {
    load();
    readimage();
}

public void readimage() {

    for(int index = 0; index < storeStrings.size(); index++){
        Image temp = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/res/"+storeStrings.get(index))).getImage();
        storeImages.add(temp);
    }

}

private void load() {
    File file = new File("Data/startUp.txt");
    try {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            storeStrings.add(read.nextLine());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] arsg) {
    imagesTest t = new imagesTest();
}
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at com.game.task.imagesTest.readimage(imagesTest.java:24)
at com.game.task.imagesTest.load(imagesTest.java:41)
at com.game.task.imagesTest.<init>(imagesTest.java:17)
at com.game.task.imagesTest.main(imagesTest.java:45)
```

Comment: My doubt is at `getResource("/res/"+storeStrings.get(index)))`. Try removing `/src/` from this. Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) example.

Comment: Thanks for the link but that is what i am trying to avoid i don't want have to write code for each image i want to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to loop through the resource folder and it was not that hard.
All i had to do use make a method and keep calling it in a loop here is the code

```
package com.game.task;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class imagesTest {

public LinkedList<Image> storeImages = new LinkedList<Image>();
private LinkedList<String> storeStrings = new LinkedList<String>();

public imagesTest() {
    load();
    start();
}

public void readimage(String f) {


    Image temp = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/res/"+f)).getImage();//looks for it
    storeImages.add(temp);//put it in a linked-List(Image)

}

public void start(){
    for(int index = 0; index < storeStrings.size(); index++){
        readimage(storeStrings.get(index));//calling the methode to look in resource folder
    }
}
//reads the text file and puts the out put in a linked-list(String)
private void load() {
    File file = new File("Data/startUp.txt");
    try {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            storeStrings.add(read.nextLine());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] arsg) {
    imagesTest t = new imagesTest();
}
}
```